# ¿Por qué no puedo contestar a una pregunta protegida?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, respuestas, reputación

En una pregunta protegida figura la advertencia:

[image]

Tengo una reputación de más de 10 con votos positivos (independiente de la reputación debida al bono de asociación), pero no puedeo responder a la pregunta. ¿Se me escapa algo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usted ofreció [200 reputación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/31780/ananias?tab=bounties&sort=offered) en recompensas; el sistema tiene las recompensas en cuenta. Su reputación 'neta' en este sitio es 66 - 100 (el [bono asociación](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/295232)) = -34, menor que 10. Es un poco extraño, sí, pero [por diseño](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231498/295232).

Comment: Pero lo que indica la advertencia es otra cosa: "**EARN 10 REPUTATION**", y no que haya que tener una reputación neta de > 10 u otra cosa. **La advertencia es, cuando menos, engañosa**

Comment: Earn 10 reputation points no es que los va a ganar. Sino que tienes que tenerlos. El inglés está mal. Deberia de ser: **You must have 10 reputation points to answer this question**. Maybe you can fix this Glorfindel??

Comment: @Lambie your command of English is probably better than mine. You're welcome to propose a better wording on Meta.SE - there's no way we can change it here.

Comment: Do you mean by creating a "separate question" here (in this forum, not under this question).

Comment: @Lambie no, on [Meta.SE]. These are network-wide settings, there's no way to change them just for [Spanish.SE].

Comment: Ok, **now** I understand. Not everyone is a computing whiz.

Comment: I think it's just familiarity with the network (which you have plenty), but I'm happy we're on the same page now :)